# SKShapeNode SKPhysicsBody Problems

Tags: ios, swift, skphysicsbody, skshapenode

I have a `SKShapeNode` that I want to add a `SKPhysicsBody` to. Here's the code for the `SKShapeNode`:

```
    let width: CGFloat = 200//self.frame.width
    let height: CGFloat = self.frame.height
    rightBlocker.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x:-width/2, y: -height/2, width: width, height: height), cornerRadius: 50).cgPath

    rightBlocker.position = CGPoint(x: -75, y: self.frame.height / 2)
    rightBlocker.fillColor = UIColor.white
    rightBlocker.strokeColor = UIColor.white
    rightBlocker.lineWidth = 10
    rightBlocker.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    rightBlocker.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    addChild(rightBlocker)
```

I've tried to add a `SKPhysicsBody` using this line of code:

```
    rightBlocker.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: (rightBlocker.frame.size))
```

but whenever I do, it completely disappears. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try setting the gravity to 0 through Interface Builder.

Comment: That didn't work.